# Error with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IParameterValues after update project to entity core 5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

After update ef core to version 5, from 3.1. I get error:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
> Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IParameterValues' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

This error show up during using Automatic DI. Did Entity removed this extensions?
Thank you

Comment: are you talking about changing from .NET 3.1 to .NET 5, or EF 3.1 to EF 5, or both? If you're changing EF 3.1 to EF 5 - that's 2 "majors" - things are allowed to change! Also, when and how are you seeing this? Is it possible that your DI config is trying to setup something that doesn't exist any more?

Answer (score 2):

this API no longer exists;

[here it is in 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.iparametervalues?view=efcore-3.1), but when you [try for 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.iparametervalues?view=efcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=efcore-5.0), it says:

> The requested page is not available for Entity Framework Core 5.0. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

So; the API is removed - that's allowed in a major, so: stop trying to configure/use it, I guess?